# 'Run' registry key to open multiple windows on specific monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, microsoft-edge

I am trying to setup a multi-monitor kiosk station to display some information. To do this, I need two Edge windows to open and each window must be on the correct monitor in fullscreen (kiosk) mode.

Up until now, we have been using a combination of Chrome and IE with 'Run' registry keys to open them. Since they are different applications, we could just manually open them first how we liked them but this doesn't seem possible with two windows of the same application.

I have been trying to find a way to do this preferably without additional software. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may open Microsoft Edge in a new window by including the switch
`--new-window` in the call.

Note that Microsoft Edge and Chrome are very similar,
but are counted as different applications, so your usual method will work
with these two.

Positioning the window on a given monitor is more complicated and requires
third-party products. Below are some such products, free and commercial;
one of them might help with your problem.

- [Dual Monitor Tools](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/)
- [WinDock](https://www.ivanyu.ca/windock/)
- [Actual Multiple Monitors](https://www.actualtools.com/)
- [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this can be done by passing the following commands to the applications in the 'Run' reg. key.

Monitor 1
--window-position=0,0

Monitor 2
--window-position=1680,0